# Why does git protocol produce more objects than git-http-backend?

Tags: git

I'm using **Git 1.7.1** configured with `git-http-backend` ([Smart HTTP](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html)).  I wanted to see how much faster this was compared to the **git://** protocol, since now they are supposed to be on par.

Turns out **git://** protocol is compressing more objects (*33,229* vs *21,193*) for the **exact** same repo (even verified client side), and thus creating a packfile that's about 30MB bigger for my project.

Is there some reason why **git://** protocol needs more objects?

## git:// Output

```
remote: Counting objects: 44510, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (33229/33229), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (44510/44510), 124.07 MiB | 2.84 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 44510 (delta 22755), reused 15866 (delta 7516)
Resolving deltas: 100% (22755/22755), done.
```

## http:// Output

```
remote: Counting objects: 24299, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (21931/21931), done.
remote: Total 24299 (delta 7517), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (24299/24299), 95.95 MiB | 2.41 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7517/7517), done.
```

Comment: Looking at http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html, maybe the the fact that Apache can be used to return static files that are stored on disk makes a difference.

Comment: have you made sure, that, after a push to the git repsitory on the server, the `post-update.hook` executes `exec git update-server-info` ?

Comment: yes, I have it exactly like that.  I'm not sure about Apache returning static files because the "manifest of files" are in the packfile that git-http-backend creates to deliver to the client.  All files as such as on the disk.

Comment: Are the contents of .git/refs/remotes/your-remote identical for both methods?

Answer (score 1):

May be:
via git you download files from all branches and you can quickly switch between them, 
via http you download only master branch.

Comment: That's a good thought, but I haven't created any branches.  Just did a git init for a base set of code and did git clone --bare to put it under /var/www/html for Apache.  Maybe that's it!  git clone --bare is just the bare repo whereas when your using git:// protocol you're pointing to the whole repo without that level of abstraction (i.e., I just add .git-daemon-export-ok to where the *full* repo is located).  Could that be it?